# Fill PDF template acrofield with repetative data using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am able to fill the PDF template acrofields, but I have a template which has a grid
[image]

It may have more than one row and it should add rows dynamically. Is it possible to fill this kind of template using itextshrarp, If yes then what should be the approach to achieve this.

I am using Libra Office for creating the PDF template and C# to update it.

Comment: No, that's not possible. All AcroForm fields in a PDF form are defined using absolute coordinates. They are fixed on the page and not repeatable. You could buy Adobe LiveCycle Designer and create an XML Forms Architecture (XFA) form, which will result in a dynamic form (XFA is XML wrapped in PDF), but be aware that XFA will be deprecated in PDF 2.0 and that the industry is abandoning XFA.

Comment: Thank you @BrunoLowagie for this valuable comment. since XFA will not be in industry,  Should we create the PDF manually (loads of code) or is there any other way to achieve because we already have some templates. (I have itextshrap licence version )

Comment: There are many different options, but if you are using iText 5, you could create your template using simple HTML + CSS, populate the HTML with data and use iText's XML Worker to convert to PDF. If you are moving to iText 7, please contact your sales account manager at iText Group and ask for "project Tyrion" (which is the code name for a designer + conversion engine).

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I appreciate your help, I will definitely try iText's XML Worker, I found [this]http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/flatsite.html as example, written in java, where can i find C# demo?

Comment: Also, Can I use iText's XML Worker for multipage template

Comment: There are plenty of C# examples on the iText web site as well as on Stack Overflow. See for instance: http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-convert-html-pdf As for a multipage template: if you convert the HTML to iText objects, you can organize these objects in different ways. You can even introduce custom tags (e.g. you could intoduce a `<date />` tag that inserts the current date).

Comment: Seems it's much slower, I tried with simple text.